# Why is Craft storing so much temporary files inside the server tmp folder?

Tags: server, imagick, filecache, storage

For several websites (Craft CMS 2 & 3), servers ran out ot storage even if these websites were not storing a lot of assets.

After looking for why, I ended up in the temporary (tmp/) folder of these servers (which is at a lower level of these vhosts), where I found there were a lot of Craft-related filed that were not purged.

These are, for example:

- Imagick files (some of them have a size of ~500 Mb!)
- A lot of Twig PHP folders and files (which content looks very similar as found in `/storage/runtime/`)

**Questions:**

- When and why these files are generated?
- Why they are not automatilcally deleted?
- When is it safe to delete them?

*To be more specific:*

- Because I'm using Imgix, front-end image transforms are delegated to this remote service;
- In this case, I think that only the CP uses Imagick;

Answer (score 2):

Imagick uses the `/tmp` folder by default, but you can change it: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/399#issuecomment-285793433

Comment: Thank you Brad. Would you mind to answer to this important point → _When is it safe to delete them?_

Comment: Generally speaking, I'd say if it's in the tmp folder, I'd guess it'd be safe to delete. If a tmp file was currently in use, you'd get an error message saying so.